# C# blob to image and preview it

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, blob

Good morning, I'm new to C# I need guidance how to convert Blob to Image and showing it on http

this is the code I'm using to convert Base64string to image on ASPX.CS
it says error
"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

```
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        string base64string = dr["img_ktp"].ToString();
        byte[] blob = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.jpg", blob);
```

This is how I'm planing to preview it on ASPX
I really don't know hot to link this two

```
        <img [src]="ImageSource" />
```

Thanks appreciate your helps

Comment: Your image might also contain type of image. Verify what base64 string you are getting. Remove unnecessary things from the string and then provide that string to the function. data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS

Comment: https://base64.guru/tools/validator site you verify if you have proper base64 string.